# what is the span of an optical fiber?

Tags: digital-communications, optics, optical-fibre

I am new to the fiber-optic communication systems, and in reading some relevant papers, I faced to the term "span length" (such as long-span link) which I cannot distinguish it from the length of the cable.

For example in one of the figures, it has depicted a quantity for various spaning lengths vs. the length of the cable.

Can anyone explain what is the "span length" of a fiber-optic link? I surfed the internet, but did not get any answer.

Comment: could you add a reference to "some relevant papers"

Comment: sure, for example see figure 4 of the following paper:

Comment: https://www.osapublishing.org/DirectPDFAccess/81DCC113-9D80-EBB6-2486E84837FC60A3_289551/oe-22-12-14199.pdf?da=1&id=289551&seq=0&mobile=no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fibre optic cables are fairly lossy. As such a signal can only be transmitted so far down a piece of "glass" before they must be received by a transceiver or relay device that decodes the optical signal, regenerates it and transmits it out again. This is a span.

The "cable length" itself could go from north America to Europe. A span may be only a kilometer.

ADDITION: That does not only apply to fibre-optics though. Any high frequency communication system, other than point to point micro-wave, needs the same "pass-the-bucket" handling.

Comment: Point-to-point microwave does have the same problem...

Answer (score 4):

In this context, a span is the cable length between two amplifying stations.

Answer (score 1):

Span in a ADSS cable is the aerial distance between two poles or towers, meaning the physical resistance of the jacket to support its own weight